# Does the solutions to an equation imply the form of the equation?

Tags: functions

I had a discussion which I actually find quite interesting. The problem was, if $x=\sqrt4$ then $x=-2$ or $x=2$. But does the implication go the other way too?

The solution from the textbook stated no.

Comment: Please state your question clearly in the body of the question and not just in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all. For instance, the equation 
$$
x^4 - 16 = 0
$$
also has those two as its only real-number solutions.

By the way, although your book perhaps did not say it, most mathematicians** take $\sqrt{4}$ to mean "the non-negative number whose square is $4$", i.e., $+2$. So many of them (including me!) would object to the statement that $x = \sqrt{4}$ has $x = -2$ as a solution.

**As Blue points out in the comments, "most" is probably not strong enough. I should say "almost every" or "every one I've ever met".

On the other hand, the equation
$$
x^2 = 4
$$
*does* have two solutions, namely $x = 2$ and $x = -2$.

I want to add that this is a great question --- in mathematics, sometimes we find something that works in one direction, and the natural question to ask is "does it work in the other direction, too?" In this case, the answer is "No, solution sets don't determine the form of equations." But if you're willing to slightly alter the question and ask, "If $p$ and $q$ are two *polynomials*, and $p(x) = 0$ and $q(x) = 0$ have the same solutions, must $p$ and $q$ be the same?", then the answer is **almost** yes!

First, you have to allow complex number solutions, and second, one of them might be not *equal* to the other, but merely a constant multiple of the other, so that 
$$
x^2 + 13x + 7 = 0
$$
and 
$$
10x^2 + 130x + 70 = 0
$$
end up having the same solution sets.

And finally, you have to allow for something called "multiplicity of a solution," which makes everything a little more messy. But the gist is still there: after a little work, we really do get a correspondence between solutions-with-multiplicity and polynomials (up to nonzero multiples).

Comment: How about any other $ax^2=4$ for some real $a$?

Comment: I was answering the question in the title: does the set of solutions to an equation imply the form of the equation? I was pointing out that over the reals, there are many different equations whose solution sets are all $\{2, -2\}$, including $x^2 = 4, x^4 = 16, (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 1) = 0,$ etc. I'm sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Mathiaspilot123: unless $a = 1$, this equation does not have $\{2, -2\}$ as its solution set. For instance, if $a = 4$, then the only solutions to $4x^2 = 4$ are $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: @JohnHughes: thanks for the clarification. I think it would have been a good idea to get the OP to state the question in the body of the question and not just in the title.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant $a(x^2-4)=0$.

Comment: @JohnHughes: "*most* mathematicians ..."? "*many* of them ..."? I believe you are *grossly* underestimating here. :) When we write $\cos 30^\circ = \sqrt{3}/2$, the sign of the value is not ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, Blue. I was trying to allow for the possibility that some folks might, in some odd circumstance, allow that. I'll edit.

Comment: @JohnHughes: If it happened, the *folks* would be odder than the *circumstance*. ;) Seriously, though: the definition isn't in question. Note, for instance, that the "one-liner" definition of absolute value (for real $x$) is $|x|:=\sqrt{x^2}$, which intentionally *exploits* the (universally agreed-upon) non-negativity of the square root.

Comment: @Mathiaspilot123: yes, $a(x^2 - 4) = 0$ has the same solutions as $x^2 - 4 = 0$, for any nonzero value of $a$. If $a$ is zero, however, the solution sets are wildly different. This is an example of the phenomenon I was describing in my last paragraph.